# Stm32 project configuration using CMake

Tags: c, cmake, stm32, cmakelists-options, cmake-language

i have recently switched my stm32 project to CMake to be independent on IDE. Root repository (application) contains multiple submodules (HAL, FreeRTOS etc.) and its CMakeLists.txt includes explicitly every single used file:

```
set(EXECUTABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE}
    
    # Own sources
    src/main.c
    src/SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Config_FreeRTOS.c
    src/startup_stm32h723zgtx.s
    src/stm32h7xx_hal_timebase_tim.c
    src/system_stm32h7xx.c

    # Base CMSIS and HAL library
    lib-hal/stm32h7xx/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim.c
    lib-hal/stm32h7xx/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim_ex.c
    lib-hal/stm32h7xx/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart.c
    lib-hal/stm32h7xx/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_rcc.c
    lib-hal/stm32h7xx/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_rcc_ex.c
            
    #long list of HAL c files there...

    # FreeRTOS library
    lib-freertos/croutine.c
    lib-freertos/event_groups.c
    lib-freertos/list.c
    lib-freertos/queue.c
    lib-freertos/stream_buffer.c
    lib-freertos/tasks.c
    lib-freertos/timers.c
    lib-freertos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM7/r0p1/port.c
    lib-freertos/trace/Sample/FreeRTOSV10/SEGGER_SYSVIEW_FreeRTOS.c
    lib-freertos/trace/SEGGER/Syscalls/SEGGER_RTT_Syscalls_GCC.c
    lib-freertos/trace/SEGGER/SEGGER_RTT_ASM_ARMv7M.S
    lib-freertos/trace/SEGGER/SEGGER_RTT_printf.c
    lib-freertos/trace/SEGGER/SEGGER_RTT.c
    lib-freertos/trace/SEGGER/SEGGER_SYSVIEW.c
    )
    
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE}
    PRIVATE
    include
    src
    
    lib-hal/stm32h7xx/CMSIS/Include
    lib-hal/stm32h7xx/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include
    lib-hal/stm32h7xx/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
    
    lib-freertos/include
    lib-freertos/trace/Config
    lib-freertos/trace/SEGGER
    lib-freertos/trace/Sample/FreeRTOSV10/
    lib-freertos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM7/r0p1
    )
```

This solution works but i know it is not a sustainable approach. So i tried to create library in lib-hal and lib-freertos submodules, specifying their sources and includes

```
add_library(lib-hal-stm32h7xx)

target_include_directories(lib-hal-stm32h7xx
    PUBLIC
    CMSIS/Include
    CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include
    STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
    PRIVATE
    STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src
)

target_sources(lib-hal-stm32h7xx
    PRIVATE
    STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim.c
    STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_tim_ex.c
    STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_uart.c
    STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_rcc.c
    STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32h7xx_hal_rcc_ex.c

    #long list of HAL c files there...
)
```

and then using

```
add_subdirectory(lib-hal/stm32h7xx)
add_subdirectory(lib-freertos)
```

and

```
target_link_library(${EXECUTABLE} lib-freertos lib-hal-stm32h7xx)
```

to "import" submodules into application project. But when building the executable, gcc cannot access files **stm32h7xx_hal_conf.h** and **FreeRTOSConfig.h** which are located in root directory *include*. I do not want to put configuration headers into submodules because they are used in multiple projects with different configurations. Is it possible to somehow extend already specified directory search scope for library after adding it into parent project?

File structure of project:

```
-src
-include (configuration for lib-hal and lib-freertos included there)
 -lib-hal
  -includes...
  -sources...
 -lib-freertos
  -includes...
  -sources...
```

Thanks in advance for response.

Comment: "Is it possible to somehow extend already specified directory search scope for library after adding it into parent project?" - You could call `target_include_directories` after definition of a library at **any time**, even from another directory. E.g. you could call `target_include_directories(lib-hal-stm32h7xx PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` from the root `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tsyvarev mentioned in the comments, you can modify the properties of the target in your project. To keep things clean, I usually create a function for this and place it in a separate file.

Tip: you can also add source files to the target. In case of FreeRTOS, you could add architecture-specific files, in case all your projects don't run on the same MCU family.

```
function(configure_freertos target_name)
    target_sources(${target_name}
        PRIVATE
            lib-freertos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM7/r0p1/port.c
    )

    target_include_directories(${target_name}
        PUBLIC
            include
            lib-freertos/portable/GCC/ARM_CM7/r0p1
    )
endfunction()
```